# Access a webform from different locations asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using a MasterPage for two webForms one in the same folder as the MasterPage, and the other one in a folder within. Should be something like this:

```
MasterPage
WebFormA.aspx
   Folder/WebFormB.aspx
```

Now, I have a navigation menu in the master, one of the menu items refers to `WebFormA.aspx` and another one to `WebFormB.aspx` The thing is that because of the two WebForms are in different folders, I'm having problems to get the current path in order to do the `Response.Redirect`, for instance if I'm in the root should be: `Response.Redirect("WebFormA.aspx")` but if I'm in the Folder should be: `Response.Redirect("Folder/WebFormA.aspx")`

Any idea on how can I go to one WebForm or to another no matter the location of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `~` character to indicate the root path of your application and use it in this way

```
Response.Redirect("~/Folder/WebFormB.aspx");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("~/WebFormA.aspx");
```

No matter in wich folder you are, because you are specifying the path of your WebForms based in the root path of your application.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use the "~" sintax.

Using the tilde you explicitly tell the compiler to start from the root of the website.

In this way you can call:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Folder/WebFormB.aspx");
```

For form B, and:

```
Response.Redirect("~/WebFormA.aspx");
```

For form A.

More information on the tilde char here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396